# is !! an implicit coercion, is Boolean() not exactly same as?

Tags: javascript

I just want to know if `!!` is implicit coercion or explicit coercion.

e.g.

```js
    const a = null;
```

is `Boolean(a)` not exactly same as `!!a` ?

Comment: Yes, exacly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` operator [is evaluated as](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-logical-not-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Let oldValue be ! ToBoolean(? GetValue(expr)).
> 3. If oldValue is true, return false.
> 4. Return true.

Where in step 2 as you can see `ToBoolean` is performed.

Then `Boolean` call [is defined as](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-boolean-constructor-boolean-value)

> 1. Let b be ! ToBoolean(value).
> 2. If NewTarget is undefined, return b.
> 3. Let O be ? OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%Boolean.prototype%", « [[BooleanData]] »).
> 4. Set O.[[BooleanData]] to b.
> 5. Return O.

Where the step 1 is also `ToBoolean`.

Hence it makes `!!expr` identical to `Boolean(expr)`

Comment: So basically both are explicit coercion?

Comment: That's correct, they both are explicit. Implicit conversion happens when the target and source types don't match, eg: `if (5) {}`. Or `1 + "a"`

Comment: @@zerkms But I see eslint `no-implicit-coercion` rules lists `!!` https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-coercion

Comment: @Gautam you could ask them why they call an explicit conversion implicit.

Comment: I did asked them in their chat forum lets see what they say. But anyway thank you for detailed explanation.